# Map view returns error 400

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am using MapKit in my app and trying to pin a coordinate (in Simulator).

In the map view, I can see the pin but the map is not loading and I get the following error in the console:

> /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer_Sim/ProtocolBuffer-91/Runtime/PBRequester.m:687 server returned error:400

Answer (score 1):

```
//First in your .h file make an object of mapview
 MKMapView *mymapView;
```

// Then in viewDidLoad of your .m file add this

```
mymapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
mymapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
mymapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
[mymapView setDelegate:self];
mymapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

annotation *ann = [[annotation alloc]init]; //annotation is my custom class of markers
ann.title = @" ";
ann.subtitle = @" ";
ann.coordinate = yourCordinates;
[mymapView addAnnotation:ann];

//Make sure that you have successfuly added the MapKit framework
```

Comment: hope that you can make your custom class for annotations if not i will be happy to provide you mine one :) sorry for my bad english cause it is not  my native language

Comment: Thnks naveen .When I ran the code on device, seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the map in the Map app loading? If you're talking about the google base map and it doesn't load in your app, but does in the official Map app, then there are lots of people who want to know how you did that because there is no known way to block those tiles.